# Magento Cache Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, menu, topmenu

I am using magento 1.9 version. In my site i enabled menu highlightion when it is clicked using php. It is working fine when disabled the cache.

But after enabled cache it highlights the previous selected menu until i cleared the cache.

How to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a typical case of block cache. The footer and header have block cache enabled by default.

You could copy over the file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php
```

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php
```

Then look at the function getCacheKeyInfo().
You will want to add a value to the $shortCacheId which makes it unique to the current selected menu option.

```
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();

$shortCacheId = array(
    'TOPMENU',
    Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
    Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName(),
    Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('template'),
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(),
    'template' => $this->getTemplate(),
    'name' => $this->getNameInLayout(),
    $this->getCurrentEntityKey(),
    $currentUrl
);
```

Something like that, not sure the current url is the option as it could be quite long.